# How to mock a data of Task<HttpResponseMessage>? C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I am trying to setup a mock function but I cant return the right data
I'm getting the error of :

`Error  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage>'`

Here is the interface I am trying to Mock

```
public interface ICouchDbClients
{
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> AuthenticatedQuery(Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>> query, string name, HttpClient client);
}
```

This is the setup that Im trying

```
var httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage
{
   StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Created
};

mockStateFixture.MockCouchDbClient.Setup(x => x.AuthenticatedQuery(
    It.IsAny<Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>>(),
    NamedHttpClients.COUCHDB,
    httpClient))
    .Returns(httpResponseMessage);
```

Comment: `ReturnsAsync(httpResponseMessage);`?

Comment: Im so dumb.. I forgot that its that simple lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ReturnsAsync` to return `Task<T>`, try this:

```
mockStateFixture.MockCouchDbClient.Setup(x => x.AuthenticatedQuery(
    It.IsAny<Func<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>>(),
    NamedHttpClients.COUCHDB,
    httpClient))
    .ReturnsAsync(httpResponseMessage);
```

it is actually the same as `Returns(Task.FromResult(httpResponseMessage))`